# C++ ostream operator issue

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ostream

Hi I have this ostream operator that gives me this error when I compile: `cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'`

here is my code:

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, CService &obj);

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, CService &obj) {

os<<obj.m_strClient;
return os;

}
```

I tried returning `ostream&` but that doesn't fix the problem, instead it adds another error `syntax error : ';'`

Here is my entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class CService {
private:
    string m_strClient;
    string m_strSeller;
    int m_iMinutes;

public:
    CService() {

        m_strClient="N/A";
        m_strSeller="N/A";
        m_iMinutes=0;
    }

    CService( string c, string s, int m ) {

        m_strClient=c;
        m_strSeller=s;
        m_iMinutes=m;

    }

    CService(const CService &obj ) {

        m_strClient=obj.m_strClient;
        m_strSeller=obj.m_strSeller;
        m_iMinutes=obj.m_iMinutes;

    }

    string GetClient() {

        return m_strClient;

    }

    string GetSeller() {

        return m_strSeller;

    }

    int GetMusic() {

        return m_iMinutes;

    }

    CService CService::operator =(CService obj) {

        m_strClient=obj.m_strClient;
        m_strSeller=obj.m_strSeller;
        m_iMinutes=obj.m_iMinutes;
        return *this;

    }

    bool operator < (const CService &obj) const {

        return m_strSeller<obj.m_strSeller;

    }

    CService CService::operator +(const CService &obj) const {

        return CService( m_iMinutes+obj.m_iMinutes );

    }

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, CService &obj);



    bool CService::operator==(CService &obj) {

        return (obj.m_strSeller==m_strSeller);

    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, CService &obj) {

    os<<obj.m_strClient;
    return ostream&;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where do you have that `friend` declaration?

Comment: Using `ClassName::MemberFunctionName` inside the class is wrong. Put a declaration in the class (`void foo();`) and do `void ClassName::foo(){}` outside of the class, or just put the definition in the class without using the scope resolution operator.

Comment: If that really is your entire code and it's a header, it should have include guards.